# Userdefaults for complications are nil while watch is working fine

Tags: swift, swiftui, apple-watch-complication, clockkit

I'm able to successfully send userdefaults from the phone to the watch using applicationContext and save those userdefaults to the app group I created. For the watch, I see all the userdefaults come in successfully and I'm able to use them in the WatchOS app.

Once I created the complications for the watch app, I am using the same app group ID and I added that app group in the capabilities of the watch extension but when I try to use the same userdefault that I'm using for the watch, everything is nil. I'm not understanding what I'm doing wrong. How do I share userdefaults between the watch and complication?

This is how I'm bringing in the userdefaults from the phone to the watch

```
    func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveApplicationContext applicationContext: [String : Any]) {
        
        let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: K.appGroupID)
        
        if let value1 = applicationContext["lat"] as? Double {
            defaults?.setValue(value1, forKey: "lat")
        }
        if let value2 = applicationContext["lng"] as? Double {
            defaults?.setValue(value2, forKey: "lng")
        }
```

I am able to use this exact function in the watch app, but in the complication, the userdefault is nil.

```
func sunsetTime() -> String {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.timeStyle = .short
    formatter.timeZone = .current
    
    let defaultLoad = UserDefaults.init(suiteName: K.appGroupID) 
    if defaultLoad!.bool(forKey: "timeFormat") == true { **this is nil**
```

I tried to remove and re-add the app group but that didn't work either. I also created a separate app group for the watch and extension to use alone but still same issue.